# Solving a game using two 3x3 matrices

Tags: algorithm

I have two 3x3 matrices. One representing the actual state and the other in a "current" state.

```
Actual state -> 1,2,3
                5,7,6,
                9,8,x

Current state1 -> 3,1,2
                  x,6,7
                  8,9,4
```

I need to bring the current state matrix to the original state by doing only swaps of element x and its adjacent element in horizontal or vertical direction.(diagonal is not allowed).

```
E.g. Current state 2 can be x,1,2  or 3,1,2 
                            3,6,7     6,x,7  
                            8,9,4     8,9,4
```

I can solve it till it reaches this state

```
current state n -> 1,2,3
                   5,7,6
                   8,9,x
```

I am clueless how to proceed to the original state after this, that is swapping two elements. Could you help me here?

Thanks

Comment: your "actual state" has a 5 in it, your "current state" a 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, assuming you are talking about a puzzle like this (only smaller)

[alt text http://www.maukatoyventures.com/images/T/Number%20Puz%20Wall%20Panel.jpg](http://www.maukatoyventures.com/images/T/Number%20Puz%20Wall%20Panel.jpg)

then you can use most any graph search algorithm (Depth-First Search, Breadth-First Search, A* if you want to get fancy) to solve it. There is a decent overview of these as they apply to this specific problem [here](http://jsl.sourceforge.net/search.html). There is also a massive amount of information about all of these floating around on the web.